# Mage registry key "_resource_singleton/newsletter/subscriber" already exists

Tags: magento-1.8, registry

i get this error since i upgraded to 1.8.1.0 when i click on a customer to edit.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function loadByCustomer() on a
>   non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php on
>   line 267

It's this line: `$this->getResource()->loadByCustomer($customer);`

When i var_dump `$this->getResource()`, i get the following exception:
***Mage registry key "_resource_singleton/newsletter/subscriber" already exists***

I understand the problem but how to fix this?? Thanks.

Comment: First off make sure the Mage_Newsletter module is enabled. If it is, try switching off caching.

Comment: You probably had some customization on the `Mage_Newsletter` extension (`$this->getResrouce()` is supposed to be of class `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Resource_Subscriber`). So, check if your `Mage_Newsletter` module has been modified in any way and go from there.

Comment: The first advice is more relevant. This error appear when you trying to create Mage::getResourceSingleton(...) and it returns FALSE. The next call will cause this error.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the `etc/modules/Mage_All.xml` file was edited and the `Mage_Newsletter` was set to `<active>false</active>`. I probably edited myself and forgot i have set the newsletter module to false. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: So to fix what did you do? I've same problem but with `_resource_singleton/sales/quote_item_option` and I've no idea of what to search and where